# Lock face surfaces to each other?

Tags: modeling

I Want to run this along the surface of a face and then rotate it on the Y and X axis how can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what to move and rotate along what ? As it seems to be you want to grab face which contains selected edges - but where ? And what are you going to rotate ? It would help if you mark steps on your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "snap to face" :

[image]

Then move each vertice to the face :

[image]

And have this result :

[image]

But it wont automatically rotate or anything.
For "rotation" or other smoothing effects on the shape, this is to be done manually (I am quite sure there is no other way to do it, **except if the rotation aspect is clarified in the question**).